# footnote gives error in minipage environment with cta-author class

Tags: footnotes, minipage

I need to use \footnote in a minipage environment, but it always gives an error

> Command \itshape invalid in math mode. a\footnote{

```
\documentclass{cta-author}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    Column 1 & Column2 \\
    a\footnote{footnote example} & b\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Latex class file is [here](http://digital-library.theiet.org/files/IET_Author-doublecolumn-submission.zip)

Answer (score 4):

First a MWE. Much of your example was unnecessary for producing the issue. This is sufficient.

```
\documentclass{cta-author}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
Foo\footnote{bar}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

The problem arises due to the `cta-author` class which interacts poorly with `minipage`. In particular, it defines

```
\def\@makefnmark{$^{\@thefnmark}$}%
```

That is, it typesets the footnote mark in math mode. The interaction with `minipage` comes from the fact that `minipage` redefines how the footnote mark is displayed.

```
\def\thempfootnote{{\itshape\@alph\c@mpfootnote}}
```

These two together cause the error, "`\itshape` invalid in math mode."

You can redefine `\thempfootnote` to avoid this issue. Here's a complete example based on your example code.

```
\documentclass{cta-author}
\renewcommand\thempfootnote{\alph{mpfootnote}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    Column 1 & Column2 \\
    a\footnote{footnote example} & b\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is that actually what you want the footnotes on the table to look like? I normally just typeset a mark myself and then the corresponding text below the `tabular`.